# htaccess redirect case sensitive urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have subfolder on my server with a case sensitive name: http://www.domain.com/MySubFolder/page.html

I just recently found out that trying to access the same page via http://www.domain.com/mysubfolder/page.html returns a 404 error.

Is there anything I can do to change mysubfolder to MySubFolder? I tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /mysubfolder [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/MySubFolder/ [R=301,L]
```

This corrects the casing issue when a user enters the URL lowercase, but it does not redirect to the proper page. In other words, entering either domain.com/MySubFolder/page.html OR domain.com/mysubfolder/page.html brings the user to domain.com/MySubFolder. I want to keep the final part of the url (page.html) while only correcting the subfoldername.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule for getting the right URL in place:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/MySubFolder/page\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^MySubFolder/page\.html$ /MySubFolder/page.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This just focuses on the specific page right? Is there anyway the page could be a variable so the rewrite occurs for all pages within the directory?

Comment: Dynamic page cannot work here since target is specific case sensitive URI like `/MySubFolder/page.html` which can also be `/MySUBFolder/page.html`